# How can I orient this slideshow to the center of the page?

Tags: css, alignment

I am working on a site here:

http://bit.ly/1ianglg

My question is: is it possible to orient the entire slider to the "middle" of the page? One way I can think of doing this is altering each image such that there is a frame of white space around each, essentially rendering them all the same size (but visually "centered")...but is there a way to do this in CSS? Basically, is there a way, regardless of image size, to align the center of each image as close as possible to the center of the page?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet is to make the image a background image of a div, and using `no-repeat center center` letting it do the hard lifting:

```
.example {
    background:url('url_of_the_image.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

The [jsFiddle with an example](http://jsfiddle.net/AjeSF/). The only thing you need to watch is that the size of the div is larger or equal of the largest image.